# Изменения сущности сохраняются исключительно в кэше на время работы приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Доброго всем! На данный момент проблема решена, но меня не устраивает способ решения. Также не понимаю почему предыдущий вариант не работал. Теперь по порядку. Есть сайт, при регистрации на котором необходимо подтвердить email. Письмо приходит, ссылка рабочая.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(DataModels.RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase files)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

        string path = null;
        if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filename = model.Login + ".jpg";
            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/temp/Users"), filename);
            Random rnd = new Random(113);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) path = path + rnd.Next(99999);
            files.SaveAs(path);
            model.Photo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        }

        try { if (path != null) System.IO.File.Delete(path); }
        catch (IOException){ /* ignored*/ }

        var user = CacheManager.CreateUser(model);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UserAlreadyExist);
            return View(model);
        }

        if (!SendVerificationEmail(user)) ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.EmailSendingErr);
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", new {user.UserID});
    }
    public ActionResult VerifyEmail(int userid)
    {
        var user = CacheManager.GetUser(userid);
        ViewData.Model = user;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VerifyEmail(BlogUser user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) View(user);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!SendVerificationEmail(user)) ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.EmailSendingErr);
            else return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", new {user.UserID});
        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.UserNotExist);
        return View();
    }
```

Теперь о методе ConfirmEmail. Не рабочий вариант:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ConfirmEmail(int token, string email)
    {
        var user = CacheManager.GetUser(Convert.ToInt32(token));
        if (user == null) return RedirectToAction("Register");
        if (user.Email != email) return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", new { user.UserID });

        user.Verified = 1;
        CacheManager.SaveUser(user, false);
        return View("Login");
    }
```

Что значит нерабочий: Перехожу по ссылке, выполняется бэккод и меня перекидывает на страницу логина,отлично, так и надо было. Ввожу логин и пароль, и о Чудо!- я вошел, круто. Нажимаю выход. Пытаюсь зайти снова - получается. Перезапускаю проект, пытаюсь зайти - возвращает страницу логина с ошибкой, говорящей о том что email не подтвержден (так и должно быть для юзеров, не подтвердивших email). Лезу в базу и вижу, что значение verified =0. Получается, что до этого изменения сущности сохранялись только в кэше. Теперь для ясности стоит привести еще два метода из проекта. Класс CacheManager метод SaveUser:

```
        public static BlogUser SaveUser(BlogUser user, bool hashPass)
    {
        return Rep.SaveUser(new BlogUser
        {
            Name = user.Name,
            Surname = user.Surname,
            Patronymic = user.Patronymic,
            UserLogin = user.UserLogin,
            Password = hashPass ? Hash(user.Password) : user.Password,
            Email = user.Email,
            UserPhoto = user.UserPhoto,
            UserID = user.UserID,
            RegistrationDate = user.RegistrationDate,
            UserRight = user.UserRight,
            Blocked = user.Blocked,
            Warnings = user.Warnings,
            Verified = user.Verified
        });
    }
```

На hashPass не обращайте внимания, т.к. иногда мне надо хэшировать пароль, а иногда нет.
Теперь метод SaveUser класса Repository:

```
        public BlogUser SaveUser(BlogUser user)
    {           
        if (user.UserID == 0) _db.BlogUser.Add(user);
        else
        {
            _db.BlogUser.Attach(_db.BlogUser.Single(u => u.UserID == user.UserID));
            ((IObjectContextAdapter) _db).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("BlogUser", user);
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();
        CacheManager.PurgeCacheItems("users");
        return GetUser(user.UserID);
    }
```

Казалось бы все хорошо и должно работать, но нет - имеет место вышеописанная проблема. Насколько я понял, изменения сохраняются не в самой сущности, а в ее копии в кэше. При этом весь код, относящийся к кэшу проходит - дебажил и смотрел каждый объект удаляемый из\добавляемый в кэш. _db.SaveChanges тоже работает и не выбрасывает никаких исключений. 
Теперь о рабочем варианте. Изменил исключительно метод ConfirmEmail и все заработало:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ConfirmEmail(int token, string email)
    {
        var user = CacheManager.GetUser(Convert.ToInt32(token));
        if (user == null) return RedirectToAction("Register");
        if (user.Email != email) return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", new { user.UserID });

        CacheManager.SaveUser(new BlogUser
        {
            Blocked = 0,
            Email = user.Email,
            Password = user.Password,
            Verified = 1,
            UserID = user.UserID,
            Name = user.Name,
            Surname = user.Surname,
            Patronymic = user.Patronymic,
            UserRight = user.UserRight,
            Warnings = 0,
            UserLogin = user.UserLogin,
            UserPhoto = user.UserPhoto,
            RegistrationDate = user.RegistrationDate
        }, false);
        return View("Login");
    }
```

Та же проблема наблюдалась, например, с изменением количества запросов пользователем за текущие сутки письма с восстановлением пароля. При этом первый запрос попадал в базу, а вот при втором и т.д. запросе значение RequestsToday не менялось. Решил аналогичным образом.

Объясните любезные мне, дураку старому почему так происходит. Текущее решение не устраивает тем, что я по сути на двух уровнях создаю два идентичных экземпляра пользователя.

Comment: При чём тут SQL Server?

Comment: @Slava Murygin, ну если подумать, то можно догадаться, что используется база MSSQL. Вообще я ставил метку MSSQL, но видимо промазал на сервер

Comment: Да, она была, поэтому я сюда и попал. Похоже её почистили и поделом. Вопрос никаким боком к нему отношения не имеет.